# how to get the data from an getParcelableArrayListExtra<Parcelable> in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

How to get the data from an getParcelableArrayListExtra in kotlin?.

I have a Parceable data class called FoodParceable

```
data class FoodParceable(val idCover: Int, val name: String, val 
price: Double):Parcelable {
constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this(
    parcel.readInt(),
    parcel.readString(),
    parcel.readDouble()
)

override fun writeToParcel(parcel: Parcel, flags: Int) {
    parcel.writeInt(idCover)
    parcel.writeString(name)
    parcel.writeDouble(price)
}

override fun describeContents(): Int {
    return 0
}

companion object CREATOR : Parcelable.Creator<FoodParceable> {
    override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel): FoodParceable {
        return FoodParceable(parcel)
    }

    override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<FoodParceable?> {
        return arrayOfNulls(size)
    }
}
```

}

In the current Acitvity A, fill in the arrayListParceable and send it to activity B.

```
    val arrayListParceable = ArrayList<FoodParceable>()
    for (Food in listFood) {

        arrayListParceable.add(FoodParceable(R.mipmap.ic_food_meat, "Carne", 9.99))
        arrayListParceable.add(FoodParceable(R.mipmap.ic_food_meat, "Vegetales", 29.99))
        arrayListParceable.add(FoodParceable(R.mipmap.ic_food_meat, "Frutas", 39.99))
    }
    val intent = Intent()
    intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(LIST_PRODUCT,arrayListParceable)
    activity?.setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent)
```

When I get the value in activity B, in list item, I can not enter its content.

```
if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                if(data != null){
                    val listItems = data.getParcelableArrayListExtra<Parcelable>(LIST_PRODUCT)
                    listItems[0]. //ERROR

                }
            }
```

I am new to kotlin, thank you for your comments. Regards

Answer (score 3):

You have to give Kotlin more information about the type of your object list. Try this:

```
val listItems : ArrayList<FoodParceable> = data.getParcelableArrayListExtra(LIST_PRODUCT)
```